# Using Visual Studio to run Qt CMake projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, cmake

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to build a CMake project that uses Qt. Visual Studio natively supports CMake, so integrating it with Qt I just modified the CMakeSettings.json file by adding a globa variable as follows:

```
      "variables": [
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH",
          "value": "path_to_qt_installation",
          "type": "STRING"
        }
      ]
```

This directs CMake to correctly find the Qt libraries and builds the project successfully. However when trying to run the project, Visual Studio cannot find the Qt dll and link them to the executable:

The code execution cannot proceed because Qt5Qml.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

To solve this problem, I can manually run [windeployqt.exe](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) inside the build directory and then run the program. This solves the issue, however I would like to avoid this and would like Visual Studio to find the Qt dll files automatically. Qt Creator on Windows does this by default, so I would like the same experience with VS 2019.
What is the correct to solve this issue?

Comment: "Visual Studio cannot find the Qt dll and link them to the executable" - Actually, QT dlls are **found** and are **linked** to the executable. The error message is about not finding the library at **runtime**. You could either add directory with QT libraries to PATH variable or to copy QT libraries near the executable.

Answer (score 1):

In principle you could set the path in `launch.vs.json` like this, **but I don't recommend this approach**.

```
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "qtapp.exe (qtapp.exe)",
      "name": "qtapp.exe (qtapp.exe)",
      "env": {
        "PATH": "C:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64/bin;${env.PATH}"
      }
    }
```

Setting the PATH globally for the whole project is a better option. For example, gtest_discover_tests depends on the ability to run the test executables at build time, which isn't covered by launch.vs.json.

> In Visual Studio, while using a CMake project, how does add one add a path to the system path at runtime? I don't want to modify the system path globally.

In the `CMakeSettings.json` file you can set the "environment" key either globally or at the configuration level.

```
{
    "environments": [
        {
            "PATH": "C:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64/bin;${env.PATH}" // option 1
        }
    ],
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "x64-Debug",
            ...
            "environments": [
                {
                    "PATH": "C:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64/bin;${env.PATH}" // option 2
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the DLL is not in the same folder as the executable, Windows will search for the file in the folder specified in the system path.

Comment: In Visual Studio, while using a CMake project, how does add one add a path to the system path at runtime? I don't want to modify the system path globally.